# Nhibernate: Database values unchanged after session.update() and session.delete()

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate

Session.queryover() and session.save() are working well. All logics getting data from or saving data to the database are working well.Changes to database through session.update() and session.delete() are not reflected. No exeption was thrown. Using session.SaveOrUpdate did not solve this problem.
This is my mapping

```
[Serializable]
public class Requirement
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int CreditRequired { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<CourseRequirement> CourseRequirements
   {
       get
       {
           return new RequirementBC().getCourseRequirement(Id);
       }
   }


   public Requirement()
   { }

   public Requirement(DataRow row)
   {
       Id = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString());
       CreditRequired = int.Parse(row["CreditRequired"].ToString());
       Name = row["Name"].ToString();
   }
}

public class RequirementMap : ClassMapping<Requirement>
{
    public RequirementMap()
    {
        Table("Requirements");
        Id<int>(x => x.Id, m => { m.Column("Id"); m.Generator(Generators.Native); });
        Property<int>(x => x.CreditRequired, m => { m.Column("CreditRequired");});
        Property<string>(x => x.Name, m => { m.Column("Name"); });
    }
}
```

This is my logic

```
[Serializable]
public class RequirementBC 
{
    ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
    public void UpdateRequirement(int reqId, string newName, int creditsRequired)
    {
         session.BeginTransaction();

            var req = session.QueryOver<Requirement>().Where(x => x.Id == reqId).SingleOrDefault<Requirement>();
            var old = session.QueryOver<Requirement>().Where(x => x.Name == newName && x.Id != reqId).SingleOrDefault<Requirement>();
            if (old != null)
                throw new Exception("Requirement with that name already exists");
             req.Name = newName;
             req.CreditRequired = creditsRequired;
             session.Update(req);
             session.Flush();
         session.Transaction.Commit();     
    }
}
```

Logic for getting current session

```
public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    ISession currentSession = context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] as ISession;

    if (currentSession == null)
    {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        context.Items[CURRENT_NHIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY] = currentSession;
    }
    if (currentSession.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    }
    if (!currentSession.IsConnected)
    {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    }
    if (!currentSession.IsOpen)
    {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    }
    if (currentSession.IsDirty())
    {
        currentSession.Clear();

    }

    return currentSession;
}
```

From my searches on this forum and others, those who have encountered such were getting one exception or the other, but no exception was thrown in my own case which makes the problem difficult to trace.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to flush the session if you are using transactions.  Also I'm not sure about the syntax you are using for transactions.  If I were to do this it would look like this:

```
public void UpdateRequirement(int reqId, string newName, int creditsRequired)
{
    using(ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
    {
        using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var req = session.QueryOver<Requirement>().Where(x => x.Id == reqId).SingleOrDefault<Requirement>();
            var old = session.QueryOver<Requirement>().Where(x => x.Name == newName && x.Id != reqId).SingleOrDefault<Requirement>();

            if (old != null)
                throw new Exception("Requirement with that name already exists");

            req.Name = newName;
            req.CreditRequired = creditsRequired;

            transaction.Commit();     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Enclosing the transaction in a using statement fix the issue.Many thanks to @Cole W

Answer (score 0):

- It is not required to call Update() on an object already tracked by the session. (And Update() will not necessarily execute an UPDATE SQL statement.)
- Where do you open and commit your transaction?
- Your GetCurrentSession() looks weird - so far I've not felt the need to have all those check my "get-current-session" methods. Particularly the if-dirty-then-clear looks strange. I would typically expect to be able to call "get-current-session" multiple times within a unit-of-work without it have the side effect of throwing away any changes to far.

Comment: I've edited the question. Update logic now in transaction. Not working yet.